# Does OpenUDID persist even if you have removed the app?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, udid

I am researching UDID alternatives, and [OpenUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID) seems interesting.

I have done some testing and if I remove the app, and re-install again, the value of OpenUDID remain the same, I am just wondering how they do that and is the value always guaranteed to persist if I don't hard reset the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving a quick glance at the naming conventions they use, I'd say they are almost certainly using the iOS keychain.  This is the same as the OS X keychain, except it doesn't allow end users direct access the way Mac OS X does.  Even if the app is uninstalled, this information will not be removed.  It is stored in a controlled environment to prevent jailbreakers from getting it.

Comment: they seem to be doing some shenanigans with the pasteboard to allow the ID to be the same across all apps. Kinda clever.

Comment: @borrrden :- If user update ios and/or install new ios then keychain data will get remove or not?

Comment: @sunilz It will be removed on a fresh os install.  Not sure about an update.

Comment: @sunilz if iOS acts like mac OS X does, keychain will remain same after an update, and i think it will.

Answer (score 2):

They do NOT use the keychain, they use the UIPasteBoard, which is a shared OS construct that persists across device restarts. From the doc:

"system pasteboards are persistent across device restarts, application uninstalls, and restores."

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html

Comment: This seems to have changed, the docs now say "When a pasteboard is persistent, it continues to exist past app terminations and across system reboots. App pasteboards that are not persistent only last until the owning (creating) app quits. System pasteboards are persistent. App pasteboards by default are not persistent. A persistent app pasteboard is removed when the app that created it is uninstalled." meaning that no pastebards survive app uninstalls. Maybe keychain is better, but I cannot find any definitive (coming from Apple) documentation about this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [BPXUUIDHandler](https://github.com/blackpixel/BPXLUUIDHandler).

I sent an app using it 5-6 days ago and the app is approved yesterday(by Apple, which means it passed 1 May, 2013 - lose your udid's) , it persists unless the device is restored. I used it in 5 or 6 apps of mine and never had an issue with it.